# What am I doing wrong, how do I add an interstitial ad

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob, interstitial

I've been trying to figure out how to add ads to my project for days.  I'm hoping that you guys can show me what to do.  I am trying to ad the ad after the first round (First time the player dies) After they close the ad; it will allow them to play again.

No ads are appearing and I am getting errors such as:

```
09-02 17:14:53.825: W/dalvikvm(635): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40a13300)
09-02 17:14:53.835: E/AndroidRuntime(635): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 75
09-02 17:14:53.835: E/AndroidRuntime(635): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 17:14:53.835: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at     com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.android.Ad.loadAd(Ad.java:45)
09-02 17:14:53.835: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at     com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.android.AndroidLauncher.loadAd(AndroidLauncher.java:26)
09-02 17:14:53.835: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at   com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.LaserJumper.loadAd(LaserJumper.java:36)
09-02 17:14:53.835: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.screens.InGameScreen.    <init>(InGameScreen.java:51)
09-02 17:14:53.835: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at     com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.LaserJumper.create(LaserJumper.java:15)
09-02 17:14:53.835: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at     com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:236)
09-02 17:14:53.835: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at     android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
09-02 17:14:53.835: E/AndroidRuntime(635):  at     android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

My classes:

AndroidLauncher

```
package com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.android;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.GameEventListener;
import com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.LaserJumper;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameEventListener {
    Ad ad = new Ad();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new LaserJumper(this), config);
    }

    @Override
    public void showAd() {
        ad.showAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void loadAd() {
        ad.loadAd();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isShowing() {
        return ad.isShowing();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLoaded() {
        return ad.isLoaded();
    }
}
```

InGameScreen (Screen class)

```
package com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.screens;

import com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.LaserJumper;

public class InGameScreen implements Screen {
    LaserJumper game;
    boolean firstTime;

    public InGameScreen(LaserJumper game) {
        this.game = game;
        game.loadAd();
        firstTime = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        generalUpdate();
    }

    private void generalUpdate() {
        if(playerDied) {
            if(firstTime && game.isLoaded()) {
                System.out.println("hi");
                game.showAd();
                firstTime = false;
                while(game.isShowing()) {
                    //Waiting for the ad to go away..
                }
        }
    }
```

Ad

```
package com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.android;

import com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.GameEventListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Ad extends Activity implements GameEventListener{
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    public static boolean showing;
    public static boolean loaded;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("*****");
        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                showing = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void showAd() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            showing = true;
        }
    }

    public void loadAd() {
        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
    }

    public boolean isShowing() {
        if(showing) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isLoaded() {
        if(loaded) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

LaserJumper (main class)

```
package com.JrodManU.LaserJumper;

import com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.screens.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class LaserJumper extends Game{
    InGameScreen inGameScreen;
    public Preferences preferences;
    public GameEventListener gameEventListener;
    @Override
    public void create() {
        inGameScreen = new InGameScreen(this);
        setScreen(inGameScreen);
    }

    public void changeToInGame() {
        inGameScreen = new InGameScreen(this);
        setScreen(inGameScreen);
    }

    public LaserJumper(GameEventListener listener) {
        gameEventListener = listener;
    }

    public void showAd() {
        gameEventListener.showAd();
    }

    public void loadAd() {
        gameEventListener.loadAd();
    }

    public boolean isShowing() {
        return gameEventListener.isShowing();
    }

    public boolean isLoaded() {
        return gameEventListener.isLoaded();
    }
}
```

And finally, the interface GameEventListener

```
package com.JrodManU.LaserJumper;

public interface GameEventListener {
    public void showAd();
    public void loadAd();
    public boolean isShowing();
    public boolean isLoaded();
}
```

Comment: which line is `com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.android.Ad.loadAd(Ad.java:45)`?

Comment: In the Ad Class it looks like the `mInterstitialAd` object used in the `loadAd()` method have not been constructed, check if the onCreate method is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interstitial ad is inside a separate Activity `Ad` and then you instantiate it directly like this `Ad ad = new Ad();`

You should never instantiate Android Activities like that (they way to launch Activities is by using Intents), because Activities have to obey the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and Android will call through the Activities lifecycle methods.

The consequence is that the Ad Activity's onCreate() method isn't called and your InterstitialAd has never been instantiated which leads to a NPE later.

---

**Solution proposal**:

- Don't create an extra activity for the interstitial ad. It is simply not necessary at all. Instead move the Interstitial Ad initialization inside the AndroidLauncher.
- Use a Handler to manage the showing / hiding of the ad. It is described here: [libgdx admob wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx). (The tutorial refers to legacy admob, but the differences to new admob are minimal and I still think it is the best tutorial) It pretty much works the same way as you would do for a normal banner.

Comment: This will work for banner ads.  I however was using Interstitial ads, and this pointed me in the right direction.  Check out this link if anyone visiting needs help:  https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/interstitial

Comment: works also for interstitials, obviously you will have to just add an interstitial ad instead of a layout with adview ;-)